# How to redirect all web traffic to a specific page?

Tags: php, redirect, traffic

Is there a way to redirect all traffic to my website to a specific page?  My free host does support PHP.  Not sure if that is what would be appropriate for this or not.  Thank you.

Comment: If you can use an .htaccess file, and mod_rewrite is enabled, this is applicable:  http://serverfault.com/questions/32513/url-redirect-to-another-page-on-the-same-site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your host is based on Apache and supports [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), use that. Eg. the wordpress typical rewite, that redirects requests to non-existing files/folders to index.php, passing on the original URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your host runs Apache and supports .htaccess, add this line to your .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.htm
```

It does not require mod_rewrite.  It does assume that only files that are *not* found will redirect to index.htm.

Comment: But wouldn't this return the result 404 with content /index.html ? If the request is made by an application, the 404 will be considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but meta refresh might work for you

`<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://some-url.com/some-page.html">`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use .htaccess or mod_rewrite is not available, you can use a simple PHP file:

index.php

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/page");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to return redirect header with status code 301-308.
just consider to use 301, because browser will cache it when you use 301

```
<?php
   header("Location: http://www.example.com/about.php",true,302);
   exit;
?>
```