# Regarding htaccess, PHP and hidden variable passing

Tags: php, .htaccess

Alright, I have a problem. Let's say that I want to be able to visit this url

```
`forum.mysite.com/offtopic/23894/`
```

and for it to pass the variables

```
`forum.mysite.com/file.php?board=offtopic&thread=23894`
```

without anyone seeing the string. Is there any way I can do this, either with .htaccess or anything else?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619933/rewriting-url-to-hide-index-php-and-to-make-query-nice/7620000. Please lookup existing posts next time, there are TONS of questions like these on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/ file.php?board=$1&thread=$2
```

That should work if you put it in a `.htaccess` file.